# Does AWS service clients automatically refresh tokens?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does AWS service clients like `AmazonS3Client`  and `AmazonElastiCacheClient` automatically refresh expired tokens when provided with a custom implementation of `AWSCredentialsProvider` with the `refresh` method implemented to get fresh tokens using `AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient`?

I use the JAVA SDK for my development.

Comment: Also please specifiy which language sdk you are using.

Comment: If you run your application under IAM role (this role is assigned to your EC2/Lambda/Beanstalk/...), it will automatic refresh.

Comment: Can anyone provide a clearer answer to this? Once the bean(AmazonS3Client) is created, how the tokens are refreshed and reflected back to the already instantiated bean?